# Saving values in collection level and not in environment level in postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I am new to postman and I have some 200 services to automate. Now for every service I need to save some values and retrive in other services. Now can I do it by saving and retriving from environment variables.

Is there any other option other than saving in environment variable ? Like at collection level itself ? Also the environment list looks big if I start to save the values in them ?

Looking for different options ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [define collection variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments-and-globals/variables/#defining-collection-variables)

> Click ellipsis (...) next to the collection name, and select “Edit” to
>   open the EDIT COLLECTION modal. Select the Variables tab to add and
>   edit collection variables

[image]

Using code:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
pm.collectionVariables.get("variable_key");
```

Comment: so how can I set and get the values ? Same way i set the environment variables ? Like I want to set some values and then use it within the collection. How can I say to save the values at collection level ?

Comment: I am not able to set the values to the collection variables - "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" - pm.collectionVariables.get("variable_key");

Comment: @dineshbalajibingo: Working in my machine : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHc6r.gif not sure how come this issue. What is your Postman version?

Comment: My postman version is older and need an update. Thansk for the gif and explanation. That was really helpful. Thank you so much @Div